# Answer to Steenrod's question using Thom's cobordism theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am following these lectures notes [https://klein.mit.edu/~hrm/papers/cobordism.pdf](https://klein.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/papers/cobordism.pdf) and trying to understand how Thom's cobordism theorem for unoriented manifolds will show that for any topological space $X$ and class $[\alpha] \in H^n(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ there exists a manifold $M$ and a map $f$ such that $f_*([M])=[\alpha]$.

The Pontrjagin Thom-construction tells us that $\mathcal{N}_*(X)\cong \pi_*(MO\wedge X_{+})$. Also there exists a thom class $u\in H^0(MO)$ which gives us a map $u_*:\pi_*(MO\wedge X_{+})\rightarrow H_*(X)$. Now we would like to see that the the composition of maps $\mathcal{N}_*(X)\rightarrow \pi_*(MO(X)\wedge X_*)\xrightarrow[]{u_*}H_*(X) $
and the map that sends $([M],f)$ to $f_*([M])$ are equal . In page $35$ the author writes both of these maps as $S^{n+k}\rightarrow \text{Th}(\nu)\rightarrow MO(k)\wedge X_{+}\xrightarrow[]{u\wedge 1}K(\mathbb{Z}_2,k)\wedge X_+$ and $S^{n+k}\xrightarrow[]{[M]}K(\mathbb{Z}_2,k)\wedge M\xrightarrow[]{1\wedge f}K(\mathbb{Z}_2,k)\wedge X_{+}$, respectively , and we need to check that this diagram commutes. Then he claims that since in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients cohomology is the dual of homology, it suffices to check that the diagram commutes in cohomology. This part I don't understand, why is this enough ? And why is checking that the diagram is commutative in cohomology easier ?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.